# Module not found error - NodeJS Express.JS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to catch the post data from my form and when I'm done with processing I want it to render the index.html file again.

Although when I'm trying the code as displayed below, I get an error.

The error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at new View (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/controlpanel/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/controlpanel/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/controlpanel/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/controlpanel/server.js:14:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/controlpanel/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/controlpanel/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

The code:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app     = express();

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use( express.static('public/html') );

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('start processing postdata...');
    next()
});

app.all('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('html/index.html');
});

app.listen(2222);
```

Everything works fine for the GET method.
Only the POST request is causing this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, 
Laurens

Comment: `res.render('./html/index.html');`

Comment: If you intend to render static pages, you should use the `static` middleware provided by `Express` in the long run.

Comment: @ninesalt That does not work for me :(

Comment: @MilanVelebit do you mean like this?
`app.use(serveStatic('public/html', {'index': 'index.html'}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code, you should use sendFile instead if render. Render is been used with views.

```
'use strict';
let express = require('express');
// let session = require('express-session');
let app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('public/html'));

app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('start processing post data...');
    next();
});

app.all('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./index.html', {
        root: __dirname + '/public/html'
    });
});

app.listen(2222);
```

Comment: This is correct, but @LaurensvanStrijland do you *really* want to always render the same HTML static page on every request?  If that's the case, it seems like the better approach would be to render it with your static middleware and expose the rest of the endpoints as JSON API called by the clientside javascript.

Comment: @Paul I just started with NodeJS and discovered the use of template engines in Express.js! Changes my static HTML pages to dynamic views at the moment!